# nested array of literals [[1,2,3]] in batch job

Tags: mule

what happens when you want to process an nested array of literals for
example [[1,2,3]] by a batch job in which there are 2 batch steps within
each a variable and a logger. In the first variable there is an dw with
"payload ++ one" and in the second batch step a variable with dw
"payload ++ two" and after that variable a logger ? Will that nested array processed or will that give an error? and if that is processed
what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I believe you should have tried to test it yourself and see the result, and if then you had a problem ask a question.

Still I'll try to answer. The result would be an error because the expressions `payload ++ one` and `payload ++ two` are not valid. For this I mean that one and two are undefined.

The `payload` in the batch steps will be the elements of the top level array, which has only one element, the array `[1,2,3]`. The `++` operator would make sense if want to concatenate the array with another array, for example `[1,2,3] ++ [4,5,6]`.

On the other hand if you implied that one and two are variables, you should have said so, and mention what values they have.

I recommend to try it in Studio with a simple test application.

Comment: Hi aled, thanks for your reply. I made an app and tested. I wanted to know what would happen if you tried to process a nested array of one [[1,2,3]] by a batch job. The values for one and two were supposed to be Strings 'one' and 'two', as expected I got a error: Scripting language error on expression 'vars.number1 ++ 'one''. Reason: Unable to call `++` with (`Array<Number>`, `String`):
 - Expecting Type: `Array<T>`, but got: `String`. I was not sure in the beginning how the batch job would behave.

Comment: So the question was about error handling in the batch execution more than about the expression used?

Comment: Not really, I was studying the batch job lately. I was wondering whether the batch job would process a nested array of one '[[1,2,3]]'. The situation was that there were 2 batch steps within the batch job each with a variable and a logger. Each variable would add a string to the input. So I was not sure if the nested array would be processed element by element 1,2 and 3 or that it would try to process it as an array block [1,2,3]. It was the last case, so I got the above error.